I need to move my timer to center of screen and then write that i lost. I have boss hp and time. My turtle is stopping and nothing writes
def bossdie():
    global bosshp

    if bosshp == 0:
        boss.hideturtle()
        timerr.goto(0,0)
        timerr.write(f"You won!", font=("Candara", 32, "normal"))
        time.sleep(5)
        window.bye()

    elif timer <= 0 and bosshp > 0:


        timerr.goto(-200, 0)
        timerr.write(f"You lost, cuz boss has {100 - bosshp} hp left!", font=("Candara", 32, "normal"))

I tried adding and bosshp > 0 but that didn't help. I was expecting that everything stopped and timer wrote that i lost.

Please share a [mcve]. How did you define timer and where do you change it? Based on the code here, there's no way to verify that timer <= 0 and bosshp > 0 is ever going to be true.
